# How long is pneumonia contagious for?

Tags: disease-transmission, pneumonia

Is Pneumonia contagious? If yes then can anyone please tell me how long it remains contagious?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Can you please specify which type of pneumonia you are referring to? Thanks!